# SLDS icon not working in production but working in community and sandbox

Tags: lightning, managed-package, slds, svg-icon

I have a VF page which is sitting inside a managed package. This page displays a bunch of records and allows users to comment, edit and delete records.

I have used SLDS icons to display my action icons (Comment, Edit and Delete).
The buttons are there but the icons are not displaying in LEX or Classic in production but they do display in the community (In Prod). The icons are also rendering in Sandbox in LEX and Classic both. So the only place it's not displaying is in Production native interface (LEX and Classic).

This is how the buttons/icons are supposed to render:
[image]

Here's the code for one of the icons:

```
<span class="slds-icon_container" title="Comment">
    <a class="noDecoration" title="Comment" onclick="someJSMethod();">
        <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#comments')}"></use>
        </svg>
    </a>
    <span class="slds-assistive-text"></span>
</span>
```

Upon further inspection, I noticed that the `xlink:href` in the `<use>` tag is behaving a bit differently in production (LEX and Classic).

Community:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/communtiyname/resource/1559153781000/namespace__SLDS/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#comments"></use>
</svg>
```

Native:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://CLIENTName--namespace.instancenumber.visual.force.com/resource/1559153781000/namespace__SLDS/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg"></use>
</svg>
```

If you notice the 'Native' DOM - not only is the `xlink:href` pulling the whole URL including the domain name instead of starting from '/resource/...' but also the end of the link doesn't have '#comment'.

This is how the icons look in production (after inspecting elements):

[image]

Please note: I'm able to perform all my desired operations by clicking on these buttons.

I'm lost here, any help would be appreciated!
Please let me know if this needs more info. Thank you!

Comment: I had a similar issue a while ago. I raised a case with Salesforce and they confirmed that it was because of the new Summer release at the time not being on my Production. The sandboxes which I used for development already had the latest release.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Would you be able to give an exact timeline of when this happened? Also, was the issue resolved? @AjinkyaPhadnis

Comment: It happened during Last Summer's release. Yes the R&D team from Salesforce resolved the issue. However as I said, the issue was similar, not exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the info, raised a case with Salesforce. @AjinkyaPhadnis

Comment: Great, Have you got a solution for it from salesforce ?

Comment: @AjinkyaPhadnis Yes, they have fixed this in the Production environment.